# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x2524212a (code=1), thread 19632 (packagename), JNI path

Tags: android, java-native-interface, crash-dumps

I have problem as the title. In my project have used javacv, opencv. I imported .SO into libs.

I convert Bitmap to IplImage
In Activity A contains:

```
IplImage ipl = IplImage.create(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(ipl.getByteBuffer());
```

The app runs in the first time is OK, finish activity A, then create new A again:
run one more time with line code above, it finishes A at once and show log cat:

@@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x514ae1bc

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x2524212a (code=1), thread 19632 (packagename)

Class path: /data/app/packagename-1.apk, JNI path: /data/data/packagename/lib

Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: have u found any permanent solution of this problem?

Comment: Not yet, This problem happens because out of memory in android